# Setting left/top position not working in IE

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax

In a custom ASP.NET AJAX control, i have this to do some repositioning.

```
var dims = Sys.UI.DomElement.getBounds(control);
this.get_element().style.position = "absolute";
//Sys.UI.DomElement.setLocation(this.get_element(), dims.x, (dims.y + dims.height));

this.get_element().style.left = dims.x;
this.get_element().style.top = (dims.y + dims.height);
```

getBounds simply returns the x/y and width/height.  I use this to set the left/top, but in IE, it's doubling; say the coordinates are 500, 20; when it sets this on the element, its actually setting to 1000, 40.  Any ideas why?  In firefox, this works correctly.

this.get_element() returns the correct element and all, but it's not setting correctly, even though event logging says it's the correct coordinates.  When using setLocation too, it doesn't work in either...

What else in my code may be affecting it?  JQuery isn't an option here too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is using the JQuery position method; this took in the apparent offset and worked very nicely.